# Vue custom filtering input component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'am trying to create a component that have 'just' an text input. String typed in this input will be used to filter a list. My problem is that I cannot handle how to share this filter string between my component and the main app that contains the list to filter.

I tried several things and most of the time I get the error :
`Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value`

So I looked Vuex but I thinks it cannot help in this case because I can have several filter component used in he same page for different list, and I don't want them to be synchronized ^^

Here is what I have:

The filter component

```
<script type="x/template" id="filterTpl">
    <div> 
        <span class="filter-wrapper">
            <input type="search" class="input input-filter" v-model.trim="filter" />
        </span>
    </div>
</script>

<script>
    Vue.component('list-filter', {
        props: {
            filter: String
        }
        template: '#filterTpl'
    });
</script>
```

And my main app:

```
<div id="contacts">
        <list-filter :filter="filter"></list-filter>
        <ul class="contacts-list managed-list flex">
            <li class="contact" v-for="contactGroup in filteredData">
                [...]
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
    var contactsV = new Vue({
        el: '#contacts',
        data: {
            filter: "",
            studyContactsGroups: []
        },
        computed: {
            filteredData: function(){
                // Using this.filter to filter the studyContactsGroups data
                [...]
                return filteredContacts;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for any help or tips :)

Comment: You can use `sync` with `filter` prop on input component: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier - this will update filter prop inside parent component. You need to refactor input component to define `value` prop and emit new value: `this.$emit('update:filter', newFilter)`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks.I stumbleuponed this documentation but I cannot manage to make it work.

So I have to sync the prop of the component like that :
    <list-filter :label="'contact'" :total="studyContactsGroups.length" :filter.sync="filter" ></list-filter>

and then in the component make another prop named value and when the input change, fire an update of the filter prop parent?

Comment: So where do I have to put the method that emit the prop change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can synchronize child value and parent prop either via explicit prop-event connection or more concise `v-bind` with [sync](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier) modifier:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rawData: ['John', 'Jane', 'Jim', 'Eddy', 'Maggy', 'Trump', 'Che'],
    filter: ''
  },
  components: {
    'my-input' : {
      // bind prop 'query' to value and
      // @input update parent prop 'filter' via event used with '.sync'
      template: `<input :value="query" @input="updateFilter">`,
      props: ['query'],
      methods: {
        updateFilter: function(e) {
          this.$emit('update:query', e.target.value) // this is described in documentation
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function() {
      // simple filter function
      return this.rawData.filter(el => el.toLowerCase()
        .match(this.filter.toLowerCase()))
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-input :query.sync="filter"></my-input>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="line in filteredData">{{ line }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```